# How to search for a sentence +1 in a file?

Tags: java, search, text-files, java.util.scanner

Okay so i am trying to store all user input into a text file. Eg if a user enters a question i search the text file for that question. if the question is found the next line in the text file would be the answer to the question. So my output would be the found text + 1. For some reason my code just hangs when i am searching the file. For example, if a user enters "what is the name of the textbook?" the text file contains the question but I want to output "the textbook name is java" but the code hangs

Here is my code

```
public static void parseFile(String s) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {

            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile + 1);  // code hangs right here.
        }
    }

}


   public static void getinput() throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* End Initialization */
    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    parseFile(input);
}
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    getinput();

}
```

and here is my text file

```
          the current assignment is 4.5
          the class is near
          the lecture is at four
          what is the textbook name?
          the textbook name is Java
          the major is difficult
          the number of test are six
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly your code hangs? Please debug and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you once try this method with slight change?

```
public static void parseFile(String s) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("data.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
            if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());  // code hangs right here.
            }
        }
    }
```

Once it finds the question it only prints the next line.

Comment: Oh no the code just hangs right there. ain't nothing being output

Comment: @Eggz: I have tried this code before posting and it works. I suspect there is something else which is creating problem.

Comment: Here is the output: `Welcome 
What would you like to know?
> what is the textbook name?
the textbook name is Java`

Comment: when i run it on my end, this is what it does. *Welcome 
What would you like to know?
> what is the name of the textbook?*

Comment: Once you type your question and hit enter it will reach the method `parseFile`. Can you please debug the code once.

Comment: The if statement is never reached. The code loops twice and exits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77154/discussion-between-akhil-mittal-and-eggz).

Answer (score 0):

`lineFromFile` is declared as `final String` and you are trying to add `+1` to it, which you aren't allowed to do, especially because `1` is an `int` not a string. This is why it is hanging.

Do this instead:

```
 System.out.println(lineFromFile + " + 1" );
```

Comment: Even if `lineFromFile ` is final and we are having the following instruction:
`System.out.println(lineFromFile + " + 1" );` it will lead to creation of a new string literal. I don't think that would be a problem.

Comment: The code above will print `what is the textbook name?1`  for the input `what is the textbook name?` , as expected. This is obviously allowed but wont do what is its intended purpose.

Answer (score 0):

For what I know it should not hang... but let's go to the code first. *lineFromFile + 1* has no special meaning and will not give you the next line. What you need is replace this line:

```
System.out.println(lineFromFile + 1);
```

by something like:

```
if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    final String response = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

The logic is this: you already got to the question so get the next line (store it in *response*) and print it. Don't do that blindly as maybe you don't have a next line, check with *scanner.hasNextLine()* as you did in the while loop.

Update: on the hanging problem, it should not happen for what I know. Java has type conversions and concatenating a int literal to a String should result in a new String. String is immutable so the final modifier should not make the code hang. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html

Anyway, the solution doesn't include that code so should not be a problem here.

Comment: @Eggz it hangs where? You should replace that line, so it will not be there to hang... if you replace it as I proposed: does it hang? where?

Comment: @Eggz is the code actually hanging or just finishing? The program will finish without any output if it does not find the question, and it is case sensitive so be carefull to don't mix lower & uppercases

Answer (score 0):

The code will not hang on that line. try to change your code into this

```
input = scanner.next().toLowerCase();
```

Your first code is trying to retrieve the "next" line terminator. which would be the second enter if the user try to input a value.

Comment: you sure? I have tried the code by myself and it ran fine. and it does return `          what is the textbook name?1`

Comment: no i do not want to output what is the textbook name?1 i want to output the sentence after the question